# System tray/taskbar icon/notify icon with universal apps

Tags: windows, win-universal-app

Is there any API I can use to create systray icons in universal apps, or is this a no-no? In that case, what should I use instead, can I somehow integrate my app into the action center or is that MS-only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry but I think that is not possible: the only option would be to develop a companion win32 program that creates the icon and establish some sort of communication between both (the win32 app could launch the UWP app, and the UWP could send status info to the win32 app). That would mean that one of the problems should have to install the other one, it is not trivial and many users won't like to have background tasks.

I think you should try to adapt to the W10 UX: use a live tile for any status/notification, allow to pin secondary live tiles that perform certain actions, and integrate with Cortana.

Integration in the action center is not possible, unless you want to create a permanent notification that performs some action when clicked, but that would probably annoy users.

Edit (6/24/2017): It is now possible to use Win32 extensions to add this functionality to a UWP app, see [this tutorial](https://stefanwick.com/2017/06/24/uwp-app-with-systray-extension/) for reference.

Comment: This is such garbage. There are APIs that I need access to that MS hides behind UWP apps and in order to access them I give up any w32 functionality that I also need.....

Comment: @Wobbles What kind of win32 functionality you need that is not available in UWP? Also, you can use UWP APIs from win32 using Project Centennial ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root  ).

Comment: This is just dumb, we need a way to visually present to user that app is still working in background as well as to be able to use global hotkeys when main window (or all windows to be precise) are closed. And still we want easy distribution and shared logic with phone apps. These limitations make no sense

Comment: @zakius Well you have taskbar badges/live tiles/notifications for showing that information to the user, and the ability to use global hotkeys with the app closed is in my opinion not only unnecessary but downright dangerous if abused.

Comment: @ArcadioGarcia the point is that app is **not** closed, just the main window (think: instant messenger), and if the main window is closed there is nowhere to put the badge on (dock mode and pinning to taskbar are evil and I want to support reasonable configurations, not only mac-like ones)