# Windows Universal Apps and tray

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app, system-tray

I was going to write a Windows Universal App that would be running in the tray. On the tray icon there would be a context menu with several options (for adding a new timelog, for closing the current one). But according to this post [System tray/taskbar icon/notify icon with universal apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31773265/system-tray-taskbar-icon-notify-icon-with-universal-apps) there is no possibility to run the WUP in the tray. Really??

Is the tray meant to be only for the system applications and the old-kind apps?

Is there some other option? To have menu items for pinned taskbar icon, may be?

Thanks

Comment: If the primary way of viewing the app is via the tray or you want an app that will always be running in the background on a desktop PC then a universal app is not appropriate nor designed for that scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible to have a tray icon for UWP application. Previously, Windows Apps was designed to run in full screen mode.

If this is a LOB app, you can try to use a Brokered Component to access to the Tray Icon feature.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Universal apps cannot add themselves to the notification area, but the recent Windows 10 Update enables them to add items to the [JumpList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.startscreen.jumplist.aspx) displayed when right clicking on the item's taskbar icon or tile.

```
bool jumpListPresent = Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.StartScreen.JumpList");
if (jumpListPresent && JumpList.IsSupported()) 
{
    JumpList jl = await JumpList.LoadCurrentAsync();
    jl.Items.Clear();
    JumpListItem jli = JumpListItem.CreateWithArguments("myJumpListItem", "my Jump List Item");
    jl.Items.Add(jli);
    await jl.SaveAsync();
}
```

Comment: Probably don't have a last update, pfff...but thanks.